# DataView.ToTable not returning distinct values

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

I'm attempting to utilize the `DataView.ToValue` function, and while it is pulling the correct columns needed, I am still not getting the DISTINCT values. I have a `DataValue` that contains a gridview of all of the information on the website. When a client goes to download this data in a specific format, they need just the unique values to be processed into the file.

At present, I store all of the columns needed for the report within an array with the purpose of being dynamic. Once that string array has been created, I create my DataTable with

```
tblData = dvData.ToTable(true, arrColumns);
```

Despite this, the data is still coming back with **all** rows. Am I missing something? According to [this from Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I SHOULD be getting back distinct values.

Comment: read the documentation again... it is for all the columns it is distinct for, not just the ones you are asking for.

Comment: @Hogan Then can you suggest an efficient solution? Everything I've been researching points to having to copy the data, remove the columns in question, and then set the table. Also, according to the documentation: *If true, the **returned** DataTable contains rows that have distinct values for all its columns.*

Comment: Yeah, this is what it looks like in the documentation and example they show.  Are you sure all string values are timed etc and there are not non-unique items which look the same?

Comment: I did a test, it seemed to work.  Source : https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/89be893055fa72c47fe5

Comment: Adding in whitespace to a string did cause it to return two rows -- I'm going to guess that is your problem -- run trim on your data.

Comment: @Hogan I'm going to double check by playing with the query on the SQLServer, but it all looks exactly the same on the xml output. All the columns being used are printed out so visually I see nothing there that would make them different.

Comment: I'd have to see example data with the problem to help you more.

Comment: @Hogan Found it, it's due to some NULLS and how they're handled on the back end. I'll have to come up with a creative way to handle this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot that a step on the backend handles cleaning up NULLs into valid datapoints for the xml. So it was properly sorting, just the null fields were actually causing "copies".